# How to make terminal bell play an alert sound without PC speaker?

Tags: 12.10, sound, xorg, pulseaudio

How can I get the terminal bell to play an alert sound out of the regular speakers (not the PC speaker)? I have irssi set up to beep for various IRC events, but nothing happens because the beep uses the terminal bell.

Also, see my [related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/247546/5696) about visual alerts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit ~/.xprofile and add the line `pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg bell.ogg`. Then when you log out and log back in, typing `echo -e '\a'` in the terminal will play an alert sound (glass.ogg). Then I copied bell.ogg (found with `locate -i bell.ogg`) to the same folder as glass.ogg and modified the above command to use bell.ogg instead. Then, you can adjust the alert volume in Sound -> Sound Effects tab.

This solution worked on Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal 64 bit with 3.5.0-22-generic. It's from http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Beep_Audible_Bell_Ping_Fix.

Comment: So freakin' weird. I mean the complexity of doing this simple thing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Your link is broken because `Ubuntu` is spelled as `Ubutu`. The good link is: (http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Beep_Audible_Bell_Ping_Fix)[http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Beep_Audible_Bell_Ping_Fix]

Comment: Link no longer works. Gives empty page without error.